# Check if an array of array is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["fistname"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

I want to process it if not empty. I have tried:

```
if (!empty($data->User)) {
   echo 'filled';
} else {
   echo 'empty';
}
```

But this returns

> filled

**Edit after Marcin Orlowski answer**

```
$user = $data->User();
var_dump($user);
if (!empty($user)) {
   echo 'filled';
} else {
   echo 'empty';
}
```

shows:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["fistname"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is `$data->User()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand in your code the function User() of your object $data returns your mentioned array. If this is the case then $data->User() (i.e. your array) is for sure non empty since it has one entry which is the array

```
array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["fistname"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

If you want to check if the 'name' and 'firstname' properties are empty then you need a piece of code like this,

```
if (!empty($data->User[0]['name']) or !empty($data->User[0]['firstname'])) {
   echo 'filled';
} else {
   echo 'empty';
}
```

or even better check it in your class, i.e. by writing a piece of code like this in the class for $data

```
public function isEmptyUser() {
    return (empty($this->name) && empty($this->firstname));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is nit clear so I assumed your `User()` returns array you shown. If so,  you miss the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty **if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE**
>
> The following values are considered to be empty:
>
> ...
>
> array() (an empty array)

Which is neither in your case so all works as exoected. For debug purposes you could also `var_dump()` to peek the dats returned:

```
$user = $data->User();
var_dump($user);
if (!empty($user) {
   echo 'filled';
} else {
   echo 'empty';
}
```